# How to set departure atom with chemfig lewis macro?

Tags: chemfig

I'm drawing a molecule and its radicals with [`chemfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig). For the molecule, the bond departs from the `C` of `CH_3`, but in the radicals, the departing bond is centered. I tried splitting the `\lewis` structure and specifying the departure atom with `[6,,1]`, but it didn't help. How can I align the departing bond to the `C` atom, like is done for the base molecule?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{CH_3-[6]*6(------)} \quad \chemfig{\lewis{0.,CH_2}-[6]*6(------)} \quad \chemfig{C\lewis{0.,H_2}-[6,,1]*6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the page 23 of the manual. You have to split `CH_2` as follows:

```
\chemfig{{C}|\lewis{0.,H_2}-[6,,1]*6(------)}
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad it was that easy. Thank you!